Error installing packages with pacman: issues retrieving snapd database and mirror configuration
Whenever I try to download anything, for instance, yay -S visual-studio-code-bin, it returns the following error
warning: database file for 'snapd' does not exist (use '-Sy' to download)
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not find database)
 -> Failed to install layer, rolling up to next layer.error:error installing repo packages
warning: database file for 'snapd' does not exist (use '-Sy' to download)
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not find database)
 -> error installing repo packages
error installing repo packages"

Then I try to install snapd:
$ sudo pacman -Sy
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                                                                                           116.7 KiB   120 KiB/s 00:01 [###########################################################################] 100%
 extra                                                                                            7.5 MiB  1353 KiB/s 00:06 [###########################################################################] 100%
 snapd.db failed to download
error: failed retrieving file 'snapd.db' from dl-cdn.alpin : Could not resolve host: dl-cdn.alpin
warning: fatal error from dl-cdn.alpin, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed to synchronize all databases (failed to retrieve some files)

The issue seems to be with dl-cdn.alpin, and chatgpt suggests a network issue, which isn't the problem, neither is DNS or any sort of firewall. It also suggests a change in mirror, but I don't really know how to do that.
What am I doing wrong? Last time I posted this problem I articulated it poorly and didn't give enough information, I apologize for that. If there are any other clarifications I will try to answer asap.

Do you have the text dl-cdn.alpin anywhere on your system? It looks like it might be a reference to dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org with the last half or so cut off. If you don't know at all where it might be, search for it using recursive grep as root, e.g. grep -r dl-cdn.alpin /etc /home /usr /var and see if you can find it. The next question will be, why would you have a broken reference to an Alpine Linux-specific download site in Arch Linux in the first place (chatgpt hallucination?).

The name resolver is failing as I believe it should be dl-cdn.alpine. Can the OP explaine why he's downloading snaps from Alpine Linux when using Arch? Also post the result of ping -c4 archlinux.org.

telcoM I searched for what you meant and these are the first few lines of what returned </etc/pacman.conf:Server = https://dl-cdn.alpin
grep: /run/user/1000/gvfs: Permission denied
grep: /run/user/1000/doc: Permission denied
/usr/share/osinfo/os/alpinelinux.org/alpinelinux-3.20.xml: >                           Eyoung, no I can not explain that, because to be honest I don't really know what I'm doing.  I just need to download vscode, but can't seem to get it to work. With your question about the results to check my internet connection it returned fine

@BlakelySchreiber Ok, so that grep command points to the /etc/packman.conf file that contains a chopped-off variant of the dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org hostname, but it's still not clear why you are pointing pacman on Arch Linux to an apk package repository for Alpine Linux.

Please post your /etc/pacman.conf. It contains different mistakes. snapd is not a repository. Follow this guide to use snap under Archlinux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Snap

My /ect/pacman.conf exceeds the character limit. I removed the dl-cdn.alpine from the config but still have a snap problem. I'll read the guide and see if it helps

Well, I found the issue. You guys were right my /ect/pacman.conf was all messed up. I had something referencing snapd, that shouldn't have been there. I was able to download vscode but when I run it I get the following errors (next comment)

code
Warning: 'ozone-platform-hint' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'gtk-version' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'ignore-gpu-blocklist' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'enable-features' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
Warning: 'enable-wayland-ime' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.
